# Is there an elegant way of using a vector modifier and getting a new vector instead of changing the original one?

Tags: c++

A pattern I find myself constantly doing is:

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
vector<int> v_copy = v;
v_copy.pop_back();
a_function(v_copy);
```

Is there a way to do this in 2 lines? I would hope something like:

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
a_function(v.without_back());
```

Thanks.

Also if you have any idea for other cases like vector::push_back or std::transform(), I would hugely appreciate!

Comment: You can always do a lambda.

Comment: Does `a_function` _have_ to take a `vector`, or can it take a range, or a pair of iterators?

Comment: You should rarely pass a vector to a function as it results in making a whole new copy of the vector. Use `f(std::vector<type> const &)` when you just need access to the vector and `f(std::vector<type> &)` if you want to change some of the passed vector.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
a_function(std::vector<int>(v.begin(), v.end() - 1));
```

Comment: Note that this fails if the vector is empty.

Comment: This is actually pretty good for the vector::pop_back() case! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Alternative syntax along the lines of **Walid Jabari**'s answer:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> v) { ... }

std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
foo({v.begin(), v.end() - 1});
```

Note: some people write `--v.end()` instead of `v.end() - 1`. This can fail if, e.g., `v.end()` returns a plain pointer, which is a valid iterator for `std::vector`. `v.end()` returns an rvalue, and the `operator--` cannot be applied to rvalues of fundamental types.

Answer (score 2):

This is what *functions* are for.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> withoutLast(std::vector<T> vec)
{
    if (!vec.empty())
       vec.pop_back();
    return vec;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
   a_function(withoutLast(v));
}
```

Or make `a_function` take a range instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a little trick and change the function, adding an `offset` argument:

```
void a_function(vector<int> v, int offset = 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size() - offset; i++){
        //do something
    }
}
```

And if you want to iterate until the position just before the last, you could do

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3};
a_function(v_copy, 1);
```

Comment: I suggest you make it `std::size_t offset`.